# qtablewidget объединенные ячейки

Tags: c++, qt5

Добрый день.

У меня имеется несколько объединенных ячеек в `QTableWidget`, вопрос: как узнать сколько строк и столбцов объединено при клике на объединенную (или не объединенную ячейку)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При клике получаете индексы строки и колонки выбранной пользователем ячейки, например, так:

```
const QModelIndexList indexes
    = table_wdg->selectionModel()->selectedRows();

const QModelIndex index
    = (indexes.isEmpty() == false)
        ? indexes.first() : QModelIndex();

if(index.isValid() == false) return;

const int row = index.row();
const int col = index.column();
```

Далее остаётся лишь воспользоваться соответствующими методами:

```
const int row_span = table_wdg->rowSpan(row, col);
const int col_span = table_wdg->columnSpan(row, col);
```

Если ячейка не объединена с другой, то оба метода вернут единицу.

Comment: Спасибо, вроде как работает.

Comment: @ExiD, пожалуйста.